# PhpStorm code inspection allows calling methods on object without type

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

Considering following example:

```
 foreach($this->categories as $category){
     $category->getName();
 }
```

IDE do not have type for $category and do not offer autocomplete as expected. On the other hand, it does not complain about calling getName method on it but I would like to get notification about that. I have not managed to find option for this in inspection settings.

Comment: What is `$this->categories`? An array of objects?

Comment: @ficuscr yes. Why is this expected?

Comment: The IDE knows `categories` is an array. You'll get auto magic for that. The IDE does *not* know what is pushed into that array though. You can hint with a C style comment `/** @var MyObject $category /*`

Comment: for code analysis look at https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan

Comment: @ficuscr Question was not how to type hint. I was asking how to get notification about calling method on object that is not type hinted.

Comment: @Vody Does this tool integrate with phpstorm ?

Comment: @Tauri28 I use it from command line using composer before I want to commit my changes. I do not think it is integrated into phpstorm (never used it that way)

Comment: Since PhpStorm doesn't execute the code, it has to know the property type at least from somewhere. Usually, PHPDoc type hints work OK.
There are some other ways, types are being inferred during assignments and stuff, but there's no way to make PhpStorm know the type always - the feature request must be much narrower, with specific code snippets.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov Yes and I would like to see that PhpStorm does not have clue about the type of property - the thing I asked for with this topic. How does your answer contribute to that question or you are just here to spread the divine knowledge?

Comment: My bad, not really sure now how exactly I perceived your question initially.
Here's the request for the inspection to fire on the mixed type: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26667
No solution in PhpStorm yet

Comment: @EugeneMorozov I guess I did not described it clearly enough - only my English to be blamed. Thank you for the link!